# Substitute words in a string in Scala

Tags: regex, scala

Given a text, I want to match words provided by the user and replace them by another word.
Words can be delimited only by spaces, commas, or parentheses.

```
import scala.util.matching.Regex
def replaceWord(str: String, key: String, value: String) = {
  val word = Regex.quote(key)
  str.replaceAll(s"\\b${word}\\b", value)
}

replaceWord("abab ab abab", "ab", "x") --> correct: "abab x abab"
replaceWord("$ab$ab $ab $ab$ab", "$ab", "x") --> wrong: "$abx $ab $abx" should be "$ab$ab x $ab$ab"
replaceWord("$ab$ab $ab $ab$ab", "$ab", "$x") --> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal group reference
replaceWord("abab (ab) abab", "ab", "x") --> correct: "abab (x) abab"
replaceWord("abab ($ab) abab", "$ab", "x") --> wrong "abab ($ab) abab" should be "abab (x) abab"
```

It seems that dollar signs are interpreted as word boundaries and therefore it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add one more `import`:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher
```

And use

```
def replaceWord(str: String, key: String, value: String) = {
    val word = Regex.quote(key)
    val repl = Matcher.quoteReplacement(value)
    str.replaceAll(s"(?<![^,\\s()])${word}(?![^,\\s()])", repl)
}
```

See the [Scala online demo](https://rextester.com/GDC17762)

**NOTES**:

- You should also quote the replacement as `$` is special there (using `Matcher.quoteReplacement(value)`)
- You cannot rely on word boundaries if your boundaries are custom. `(?<![^,\s()])`/`(?![^,\s()])` will make sure a match is only found in between whitespaces, commas or parentheses.